# GLoVe word embedding for special words in seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, word2vec

I am training a `seq2seq model` in Tensorflow. I want to use `GLoVe` as word embedding for words in my sequences. In `seq2seq`, I am using some of tags like `EOS(End of Sequence)`, `GO(start of sequence for decoder)`, `PAD(for padding sequence)`, as words in my sequences.

But `GLoVe` won't be having embedding for these tags.
So, how should I represent these tags ?

Comment: To clarify: do you mean that you want to use a _pre-trained_ embedding? Something that you could try would be to add three new indices, one for each of `EOS`, `GO`, `PAD`. These would essentially be feature detectors that switch on whenever each of those symbols appear. So the dimension of your new embedding would be `(E: = dimension of original embedding) + 3`, with the first `E` indices given by your original embedding and the last three reserved for the special symbols.

Comment: Yeah I want to use pre-trained embedding. 
The new indices would be 1, when that tag, for ex EOS,  is there, right ?
So for `EOS` all indices will be zero except the one corresponding to it ? 
Is there any other approach which people generally use ?

Comment: Well, that would be my first attempt if I were going to do it. It wouldn't be hard to write a function that creates a tensor of shape `[batch, (...), 3]` acting as a one-hot encoding of your special symbols and then concatenate it with the output of the embedding (all dimensions should be the same except for the last one).
What you lose is any semantic association between your special symbols and your "real words", but I don't think that is a big issue since there's no semantic relation between e.g. `EOS` and the word `car` compared to the semantic relation between `king` and `queen`.

Comment: And yes, the idea is that it would be "sparse", i.e. the index/"bit" for `EOS` would turn on (`= 1`) if and only if an `EOS` is observed with no other "bits" turning on. This is different from the representation that is given when a real word is observed, which would be represented as a "dense" vector in your embed-space (with the exception of the bits for the special symbols, which would be 0 when a real word is observed). This generally makes it easy for your model to learn to treat special symbols differently. (For example if you are designing a translation model, it learns `EOS` quickly).